# How to distinguish git ignored files and directories in NERDTree

Tags: git, vim, nerdtree

I want the NERDTree to show files and directories ignored by Git in light color (i.e., dimmed) to distinguish them from tracked files and directories. How can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Modified from [nerdtree-git-plugin](https://github.com/Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin/blob/6a9b3122cb89b3a45ec444f9787a895125aca8aa/nerdtree_plugin/git_status.vim#L91), this snippet will auto highlight ignored files using `Commment` for new version NERDTree without `|-` similar prefix (which cause sync match failure?).

```
function! GitDimIgnoredFiles()
    let gitcmd = 'git -c color.status=false status -s --ignored'
    if exists('b:NERDTree')
        let root = b:NERDTree.root.path.str()
    else
        let root = './'
    endif
    let files = split(system(gitcmd.' '.root), '\n')

    call GitFindIgnoredFiles(files)
endfunction

function! GitFindIgnoredFiles(files)
    for file in a:files
        let pre = file[0:1]
        if pre == '!!'
            let ignored = split(file[3:], '/')[-1]
            exec 'syn match Comment #\<'.escape(ignored, '~').'\(\.\)\@!\># containedin=NERDTreeFile'
        endif
    endfor
endfunction

autocmd FileType nerdtree       :call GitDimIgnoredFiles()
```

Comment: I pasted this to .vimrc, when out and in of vim, and got lots of errors, startind with `Error detected while processing function GitDimIgnoredFiles[9]..GitFindIgnoredFiles:
` then followed by mostly `E402: Garbage after pattern: /path/to/a/folder// containedin=NERDTreeFile` and `E475: Invalid argument: Comment /path/to/a/folder// containedin=NERDTreeFile`. Please, advice.

Comment: Updated to fix the error, but still a simplified approach.

Comment: This can be a start for a complete and efficient solution. For example, it does not dim excluded directories and their contents.